# How to match underlined digits using Antlr4's grammar?

Tags: grammar, antlr4

I have a situation which needs to match either digits or underlined digits.

To match digits, it is easy to write `[0-9]+`.

But how to match underlined digits? How to express underlined digits in Antlr4's grammar? Can anyone help me? Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are the underlined digits represented, exactly? Can you include an example *textually* in your question? (i.e., not an image)

Comment: I know there is no formatting issue in txt file or Console. But in word document, we will have underlined text, and in my research, I must consider this situation.

Comment: Then you have to consider the question of how you are going to use Antlr to read a Word document. To be sure, the Word document could also contain numbers in **bold** or *italics*, in larger or smaller sizes, in different fonts, and so on. But these formatting codes need to somehow be serialized (say as HTML or RTF) in order to feed the data into a text processor such as a parser generated by Antlr. So the question of how the formatting information is to be *represented* is essential (and you have not yet attempted an answer).

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR works with token/character streams, so the RAW WORD document data would likey have some type of "escape" token to indicate "start underline" and "stop underline", which would be optional;

(WARNING... I'm an ANTLR Newbie but this is what I would try)

```
//
// Define Start Underline and Stop Underline tokens
fragment START_UNDERLINE : "SomeWordToken(s) possibly \uxxx values";
fragment STOP_UNDERLINE  : "SomeOtherToken(s) possibly \uxxx values";

DIGITS : [0-9]+
UNDERLINED_DIGITS : START_UNDERLINE DIGITS STOP_UNDERLINE;
```

The above likely won't work because UNDERLINING in word can start on the beginning of a sentence.  So you probably want to have the parser look for START_UNDERLINE and STOP UNDERLINE events.

```
//
// Define Start Underline and Stop Underline tokens
START_UNDERLINE : "SomeWordToken(s) possibly \uxxx values";
STOP_UNDERLINE  : "SomeOtherToken(s) possibly \uxxx values";

DIGITS : [0-9]+
UNDERLINED_DIGITS : START_UNDERLINE DIGITS STOP_UNDERLINE;

enter_underline  : START_UNDERLINE;
exit_underline   : STOP_UNDERLINE;
```

Then you could have Listener java functions for the enter/exit underline events to modify the text as needed.   You could optionally add lexer "modes" to START/STOP underline, but I have found that with IMPORTED lexers (which is what I use), the modes do not import.  So for now I'm not using modes.

DISCLAIMER... I'm a ANTLR newbie, and only have probably 30minutes-3 days more stick time than you.  Just trying to help :).

-R